# What are possible downsides of rendering same table twice (one for mobile and one for desktop)

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm building an application where I want to design a table so that looks good on mobile and on desktop devices.

My question is, if there's any downside to render the table with same content but different structure twice?

Simplified example  would be something like this

```
<!-- Show on desktops -->
<table class='visible-on-desktop'>
    <!-- Desktop table specific rows -->
</table>

<!-- Show on mobile, tables -->
<table class='visible-on-mobile'>
    <!-- Mobile, tablet table specific rows -->
</table>
```

Since the query on database is run only once I'm guessing the only performance overhead is from rendering the results twice. Also the reason why I'm not just using CSS to style desktop form for mobile version is that the desktop form is quite complex and it's really hard to make it into a good design for mobile.

Comment: If you show only one of them then you're not rendering the results twice.

Comment: @JJJ — I think the OP means rendering in the sense of "creating the HTML" rather then "displaying on screen".

Comment: @JJJ but the results still have to exist in DOM  tree right, you're just not showing it to the user?

Comment: Right, you mean parsing. ("Rendering" is synonymous to "showing on the screen").

Comment: @JJJ  yes, my bad :)

Comment: Perhaps a design change would benefit your circumstance? Design for mobile first - give the user only the necessities. Then scale out to desktop, adding things as screen real-estate becomes available. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've doubled the content you are sending over the network (especially important on slow and metered connections).

If the CSS fails to load (entirely possibly on mobile connections which can lose signal in the middle of loading a page), then the content will be displayed to the user twice.

Comment: I get why you mean with doubling the content that has to be sent over the network, but in my case if CSS fails, the whole app becomes a mess on mobile either way because it's lacking responsiveness

Comment: That suggests that you should fix the rest of the HTML rather then not considering it important.

Answer (score 1):

Possible downsides are:

- Complex HTML structure (harder to understand)
- More data send over network (negligible)
- Slower DOM (more elements on page)

If you're creating a relatively small page and minimal data usage isn't that important I would say it's okay, otherwise, try CSS media query's instead.